# Undefined symbols for architecture i386: "_CMTimeMake", referenced from:

Tags: ios, objective-c, cmtime

I don't understand why this is happening. I'm trying to us CMTimeMake:

```
CMTime cmTime = CMTimeMake(60, 1);
```

The imports of `.h` are:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
```

and `.m` are:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ContentView.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "BackButton.h"
#import "NavButton.h"
#import "IIViewDeckController.h"
#import "TutorialView.h"
```

With a build error of:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_CMTimeMake", referenced from:
      -[ViewController activateLockScreenPlayer:] in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You aren't linking with the CoreMedia framework.  You can add it to your target in the project editor, like this:

[image: linking the framework]